# How to apply top and left border in a cell range?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am a bit new on PHPExcel and I'm triying to  apply only top and left border in a cells range, each border with different colors. This is what I'm triying to achieve:

[image]

I tried with:

```
$style = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'top' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN),
    'left' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN)
  ),
);

$xls->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($range)->applyFromArray($style);

...
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want de first column #red and the rest #purple..

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($range)->getBorders()->getTop()->applyFromArray(
         array(
             'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DASHDOT,
             'color' => array(
                 'rgb' => #Purple
             )
         )
 );
```

for the left:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($range)->getBorders()->getLeft()->applyFromArray(
         array(
             'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DASHDOT,
             'color' => array(
                 'rgb' => #Red
             )
         )
 );
```

Or you can see the documentation... 
http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_Borders.html#methodapplyFromArray

Cheers,